# “search?.actionView as SearchView” crashes moving to the Second Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building a simple app (in Kotlin), which has a simple button in MainActivity.kt, that when clicked opens a second activity. The second activity has an array (from strings.xml). When the selected list item the result should be passed to the first activity.

When I click on the button to go to the second activity it crashes (on “ val searchView : SearchView = search?.actionView as SearchView”) – although it is reporting errors in the log (which I don’t really understand).

I’m using the androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView library which I had seen problems using the old library, so I don’t think it is that.

Any help really appreciated - thanks.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
```

private val SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1

```
/* THE GUTS OF IT */
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    Searchbutton.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("TAG", "MainActivity 1- JH")
        val intent = Intent(this, SearchActivity::class.java)
        Log.d("TAG", "MainActivity 2- JH")
        startActivityForResult(intent, SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        Log.d("TAG", "MainActivity 3- JH")
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult starting 100 - JH")
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    Log.d("TAG", "onActivityResult 101 - JH")
    if (requestCode == SEARCH_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        val gotthisInt = data?.getStringExtra("result")

        Log.d("TAG", "What was received  JH = $gotthisInt")
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            /* val gotthisInt = data?.getStringExtra("result") */
            val gotPosition = data?.getStringExtra("position")
            Log.d("TAG", "What was POSITION  JH = $gotPosition")
        }
    }
}
```

}

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!-- Debug - to be deleted -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textDebug"
    android:layout_width="69dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="104dp"
    android:text="DEBUG HETE"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Searchbutton"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textDebug"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

**SearchActivity.kt**

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>
private lateinit var listView: ListView
private lateinit var emptyView: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d("TAG", "SearchActivity OnCreate Starts JH")

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContentView(R.layout.search_main)

    title = "Search App"
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView)
    emptyView = findViewById(R.id.emptyView)

    adapter = ArrayAdapter<Any?>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        resources.getStringArray(R.array.vegetables))
    listView.adapter = adapter

    listView.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { adapterView, _, i, _ ->
        Toast.makeText(this@SearchActivity, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    listView.emptyView = emptyView
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu Starts JH")

    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu 901 JH")
    val search = menu.findItem(R.id.appSearchBar)
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu 902 JH")
    /*val searchView = search.actionView as SearchView CRASH */
    val searchView : SearchView = search?.actionView as SearchView  /* This crashes for my code, works here */

    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu 903 JH")

    searchView.queryHint = "Search"
    Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu 904 JH")

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val intent = Intent()
        val theItemClicked = String()
        /* Log.d("TAG", "onCreateOptionsMenu - 209 - Gets here JH")
            theItemClicked = list[position].toString() */

        intent.putExtra("result", "this one")
        intent.putExtra("position", "hello")
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
        finish()
    })

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            adapter.filter.filter(newText)
            return true
        }
    })
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

}

**Search_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SearchActivity">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorBackgroundFloating"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No Results"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

**nav_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/appSearchBar"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

**logcat Errors**
These errors are shown when I click to move to the second activity:

```
2021-01-27 22:54:47.956 1429-1429/com.dbtest.VegJanv20211 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dbtest.VegJanv20211, PID: 1429
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    at com.dbtest.VegJanv20211.SearchActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(SearchActivity.kt:55)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:4074)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:325)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3070)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1895)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2176)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:271)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2021-01-27 22:54:48.053 1967-2079/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'b8064d4 com.dbtest.VegJanv20211/com.dbtest.VegJanv20211.SearchActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-01-27 22:54:48.055 1967-2079/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '1b19412 com.dbtest.VegJanv20211/com.dbtest.VegJanv20211.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2021-01-27 22:54:49.436 2609-3310/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/ModuleIdSetter: exception when setting module id
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
        at com.google.android.chimera.config.ModuleManager.getCurrentModule(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):2)
        at aewd.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):4)
        at aewg.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):9)
        at aeso.a(Unknown Source:0)
        at rpm.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):0)
        at rlv.c(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):1)
        at rlt.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):1)
        at rok.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):6)
        at rok.c(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):6)
        at rok.b(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):10)
        at rok.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):17)
        at rok.g(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):3)
        at sdr.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):2)
        at scr.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):10)
        at sci.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):0)
        at scl.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):28)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at aekz.a(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):2)
        at aekz.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@202414022@20.24.14 (040700-319035315):14)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
2021-01-27 22:54:49.910 2609-2609/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter [CONTEXT service_id=111 ]
2021-01-27 22:54:49.938 2609-2609/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places [CONTEXT service_id=111 ]
```

These errors are shown while I am still in the MainActivity.kt:

```
2021-01-27 22:52:06.434 1967-1967/system_process E/LoadedApk: Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.dbtest.VegJanv20211-e8K-P0xolKFD4G9UM3OUYg==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:256)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:370)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1941)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:541)
    at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:908)
```

2021-01-27 22:52:06.546 2469-3889/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2021-01-27 22:52:06.818 2844-3382/com.google.android.gms E/GmsClient: unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.auth.key.retrieval.service.START on com.google.android.gms
2021-01-27 22:52:06.913 1783-2066/? E/installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl1729715317.tmp: No such file or directory
2021-01-27 22:52:07.234 1967-1999/system_process E/system_server: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2021-01-27 22:52:07.516 1429-1429/? E/st.VegJanv2021: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-01-27 22:52:08.670 1750-2559/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2021-01-27 22:52:08.676 1750-1906/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2021-01-27 22:52:09.982 1874-1874/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-01-27 22:52:10.422 1896-1896/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-01-27 22:52:11.551 2469-3889/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2021-01-27 22:52:18.366 1967-2004/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-01-27 22:52:30.088 1967-2004/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-01-27 22:52:35.879 2609-1687/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-01-27 22:52:47.310 2844-1688/com.google.android.gms E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-01-27 22:53:02.412 1967-4198/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-01-27 22:53:10.040 1874-1874/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2021-01-27 22:53:10.431 1896-1896/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2021-01-27 22:52:56.607 2469-3889/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's this line at the top of your error log:

```
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
```

which is talking about this (which you mentioned is where it's crashing):

```
val searchView : SearchView = search?.actionView as SearchView
```

So you're trying to cast the result of the expression`search?.actionView` (which **can be null**, you're null-checking it after all) to a **non-null** `SearchView` type. You're effectively telling the compiler "don't worry, this is definitely not going to be null!" but sometimes it is, and that's why the app is crashing - you're trying to cast `null` to a type that can't be null.

So you need to make `searchView` nullable, i.e. the type needs to be `SearchView?` not `SearchView`:

```
val searchView : SearchView? = search?.actionView as SearchView?
```

Comment: Brilliant! Really appreciate the help! I’ve added the mentions to SearchView and search to “?” and it works, but I still get the error “kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null…”?  Cheers

Comment: Is it pointing at the same line? Did you change both of them from ``SearchView`` to ``SearchView?`` (the one before the = and the one at the end)? You don't need the one after ``val searchView`` btw, it knows the type because you're explicitly casting it with ``as``

Comment: Have just realised what the problem was - was looking at the Logcat and it was from the previous test I did. Now I look at the latest results it wasn't showing the null problem! So many thanks for your help, that's all help me move on! Cheers